# Should I implement checking of authentication token in application's onCreate method

Tags: android

I'm doing requests to the webserver using tokens. I also have an activity with authentication form. When a user starts my application I want to check if she has token and:

- if there's one show standart first screen
- if there isn't one show login activity

To store and request token I use `SharedPreferences`. Currently I've placed the logic inside `onCreate` method of `MyApplication` to check it when application starts:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    String authToken = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        authToken = preferences.getString("token", null);
        if (authToken == null) {
            // requires authorization
            // show login acitivity
        }
```

But I'm not sure how to launch login activity from `onCreate` method if according to `AndroidManifest` normal main screen activity should be started. So now having this check in `Application` brings doubts. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend `onCreate` method as the access token might be revoked while the application is in a background state and the `onCreate` method **won't** be called again on coming to foreground.

[image]

Instead, use the `onResume` method, which is called in all scenarios. The following code shows a base activity to be extended by your other activities. If you don't need authentication in some activity, then just override `requireLogin()` method to return `false`.

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnAccountsUpdateListener {

    public boolean requireLogin(){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(requireLogin()){
           // check authentication

           if(notAuthenticated){
              startActivity(loginActivityIntent);
              finish();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should I access `SharedPreferences` inside `// check authentication` comments inside activity and discard current functionality in `MyApplication` class?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However note that this will only tell you whether there is a token. You dont know anything about its actual validity. Handling expired tokens should be handled when actually fetching data..

Comment: I see, thanks. Have you yourself implemented such or similar functionality?

Comment: Can you please take a look at my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511603/how-to-update-data-inside-fragment-from-parent-acitivity) question?