# How to update data inside fragment from parent acitivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the design like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|   search input | spinner        |
-----------------------------------
| item 1                          |
| item 2                          |
| item 3                          |
-----------------------------------
```

A `fragment` (bottom part) holds the list of records passed down from the parent activity. The data is passed through bundle when fragment is created like this:

```
fragmentTagsList = new FragmentTagsSelector();
Bundle fragmentArgs = new Bundle();
fragmentArgs.putParcelableArrayList("tags", tags);
fragmentTagsList.setArguments(fragmentArgs);

if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tagsListFragmentWrapper) == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tagsListFragmentWrapper, fragmentTagsList).commit();
}
```

The top controls (search input and spinner) belong to parent activity's UI. Whenever a user types a query into search input, I need to filter the list and pass new filtered list of items to the fragment. How can I do that? Should I call the fragment's method from activity? Is this a good approach to separate there controls in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an interface and have the Activity implement it. The overriden functions would be the ones which return real time data (in form of HashMap or array as per your design).

```
 @Override
 public DataType getMyData()
    {
       ....
        return latestFilteredData;
    }
```

In fragment onAttach callback, initialize interface's object.

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    callback = (MyInterface) activity;

    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Now you can use callback object to get latest data anywhere in activity like:

```
 callback.getMyData();
```

Comment: Thats absolutely fine. If it works with this method, you can accept the answer. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Actually, you answer is reverse of what I need :). I'd need to implement interface on Fragment - well, that's what I'm doing right now. So `@karaokyo`'s is more correct in that sense

Comment: This is standard communication between activity-fragment. Karaokyo's link is also to similar code. If you implement activity and return current data via overriden functions, your fragment has the access to latest data!

Comment: If you are worried about the calls, simply get a reference to current fragment and right a function which will in turn call interface's getter function and vola! latest data updated in fragment. I am not sure about your way, haven't implemented interface on Fragment yet!

Answer (score 0):

Call the fragment's public methods from the activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing right now. So that seems to be a correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use [otto from square](http://square.github.io/otto/)

It is simply awesome event bus library for android. It will keep your code **loosely coupled** and **clean**.

Example usage:

```
//posting a event from your activity
Bus bus = new Bus();
bus.post(new AnswerAvailableEvent(42));

//receiving event in your fragment
@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(AnswerAvailableEvent event) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow!
}
bus.register(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'll consider this